# Building Unitaries in TSP Quantum Phase Estimation Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

[image]

In the paper [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10928.pdf] [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10928.pdf) published by IBM, they use Quantum Phase Estimation to solve the TSP problem. I don't understand the reason why they can decompose the diagonal unitary matrix U(j). Is that their own work to find the two multiplying components in the form of P-gates to have the unitary matrix U at the end, or have they followed the lemma or some other form to decompose? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The screenshot is from a  web source? It is not clear what's the purpose of that screenshot. Also, be specific, indicate the page and equation you have questions about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I wonder how they can construct the unitary matrix U from decomposing it in terms of controled-unitaries. I wonder if they can decompose the U matrix from the tensor product of two 2x2 matrix tensor products and element-wise with the control T. How can they find the value such as e^i(c-a) or e^i(d-c+a-b). I really can't get it :(
https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/tsp.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you are struggling to understand is the very first equation from the screenshot you provided in your question. Let us suppose that we attempt to express the $4 \times 4$ diagonal matrix

$U_j = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{ia} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{ib} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{ic} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{id}
\end{pmatrix}$

simply in terms of the Kronecker product, $P_1 \otimes P_2$, of two phase-gates

$P_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{if}
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{ig}
\end{pmatrix}$

up to some global phase factor $e^{ih}$. Equating $U_j = e^{ih} P_1 \otimes P_2$, where

$e^{ih} P_1 \otimes P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{ih} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i(h+g)} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{i(h+f)} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i(h+f+g)}
\end{pmatrix}$,

we obtain four nontrivial conditions, one for each diagonal entry.

- For the first diagonal entry, $e^{ia} = e^{ih}$, so $h = a \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$.
- For the second diagonal entry, $e^{ib} = e^{i(h+g)}$, so $g = b-h = b-a \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$.
- For the third diagonal entry, $e^{ic} = e^{i(h+f)}$, so $f = c-h = c-a \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$.
- For the fourth diagonal entry, $e^{id} = e^{i(h+f+g)}$, so $d = a + (c-a) + (b-a) = c + b -a \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$.

We realize that the fourth condition can only be satisfied provided that there is a special relation between the diagonal entries of the original matrix $U_j$, namely $a + d = c + b \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$. If this condition is met, then $U_j$ can be expressed solely as a Kronecker product of two phase-gates, meaning that it is not an entangling gate, i.e., it cannot change the entanglement structure of an input two-qubit state. In general, however, $4 \times 4$ diagonal unitary matrices can represent entangling gates; the canonical example is the CZ gate,

$CZ = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$.

In this case, $a=b=c=0$ and $d = \pi$, so the condition $a + d = b + c \; (\textrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$ is not met, as expected.

In hindsight, for the general case, we could not possibly expect to decompose $U_j(a,b,c,d)$ using just $e^{i h} P_1(f) \otimes P_2(g)$ since the former has four degrees of freedom while the latter has only three. Hence, we need to add an extra $4 \times 4$ diagonal unitary matrix that allows to set the last diagonal entry to its correct value $e^{id}$. That is what the controlled-phase-gate

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i(d-c+a-b)}
\end{pmatrix}$

amounts to.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your response; it both expands our horizons and our knowledge gaps. We expanded your method for decomposing unitary matrices in order to decompose 8x8 unitary matrices. Even if we follow your instructions and use a three-phase gate to decompose it, we will be unsuccessful. We wonder how an 8x8 unitary matrix can be decomposed in terms of the tensor product of three phase gates, as this is the only way to implement QPE. Can you tell us some decomposition techniques or what we need to learn to accomplish this?
We express our gratitude and wish you a pleasant day.

Comment: You can also extend this method to decompose a diagonal $8 \times 8$ unitary matrix. You have $4$ degrees of freedom ($3$ phases from the tensor product of phase gates plus the global phase) and $8$ entries of the $8 \times 8$ matrix. Hence, you need to add $4$ controlled-controlled-phase gates, one for each of the extra entries that you could not fix with the tensor product of three phase gates. I would instead suggest using a standard method such as optimized quantum Shannon decomposition (cf. arXiv:quant-ph/0406176), which takes at most 20 CNOTs to decompose any $8 \times 8$ unitary.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new post for decomposing 8x8 unitary matrices. We wonder how we can construct 4 controlled-controlled-phase gates.
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28396/decompose-8x8-unitary-matrix-into-tensor-product-of-three-phased-gate