# Decompose 8x8 Unitary Matrix into tensor product of three phased gate

Tags: quantum-gate

We try to decompose 8x8 unitary matrices
\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{ia}  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  e^{ib}  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  e^{ic}  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  e^{id}  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  e^{ie}  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  e^{if}  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  e^{ig} \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &   e^{ih}
\end{pmatrix} using the methods answered in [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28114/building-unitaries-in-tsp-quantum-phase-estimation-qiskit),by taking the tensor product of three phase gates formed
$P_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{ii}
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{ij}
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
P_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{ik}
\end{pmatrix}$,

and element wise with the 4 controled-controled-phased gate:
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&e^{i(\lambda)} 
\end{pmatrix}

We have the result of tensor product of three phased gate $P_1 \otimes P_2 \otimes P_3$:
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  e^{ik}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  e^{ij}&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  e^{i(k+j)}&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{ii}&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(k+i)}&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(i+j)}&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&e^{i(k+j+i)} 
\end{pmatrix}

Taking global phased factor $e^{il}$:
\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{il}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  e^{i(k+l)}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  e^{i(l+j)}&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  e^{i(k+j+l)}&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(i+l)}&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(k+i+l)}&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(i+j+l)}&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&e^{i(k+j+i+l)}
\end{pmatrix}

We obtain eight nontrivial conditions, one for each diagonal entry:

- a = l
- b = l+k -> k = b - a
- c = l+j -> j = c - a
- d = l+k+j -> d = b + c - a
- e = l+i -> i = e - a
- f = l+k+i -> f = b + e - a
- g = l+i+j -> g = e + c - a
- h = l+i+j+k -> h = e + c + b - 2a

And then we put value of i,j,k,l back into the matrix when we taking the global phases factor.
\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{ia}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  e^{ib}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  e^{ic}&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  e^{i(b+c-a)}&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{ie}&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(b+e-a)}&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{i(e+c-a)}&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&e^{i(e+c+b-2a)}
\end{pmatrix}

We wonder how we can construct the controled-controled-phase gates to satisfy and achieve the original unitary matrice or did we make any mistake through our work. We would love to hear your response.
\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{ia}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  e^{ib}&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  e^{ic}&  0&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  e^{id}&  0&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{ie}&  0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{if}&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  e^{ig}&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&e^{ih} 
\end{pmatrix}